# How to merge two databases of mongoDB present in two different computers?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongo-collection

I am using mongoDB to store the data of a particular website. Since two of us are working, we are using our own computer for the job. Both the computer has a database `website_data` and a collection in that database `webpages`. Now for some analysis, and to plot graphs, I need the whole data in a single pc. How to combine the two databases? I thought of writing a script but I don't know how to connect to the other computer's database. Is there some database file which I can copy directly onto my pc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this with the command line tools [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump) and [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore).

Use `mongodump --db [dbname]` on the source computer to export all collections of the database into files which are stored in the directory `dump/[collection].bson`. Copy the files to the target computer and then use `mongorestore --db [dbname] [collection].bson` to import the generated files into the consolidated database. The contents will be appended to the existing collections as if you would use the `insert` command.

When you want to do it like a senior sysadmin: both command line tools have command line options to perform said operations on a remote system and you can pipe the output of mongodump right into mongorestore, so when you want to show off you *could* do it with one console command from a remote system. But when this is a one time thing and command line trickery is not your passion, rather stick to files.

Comment: Curious if two documents that had the same _id will cause error, be treated as the same document and hence ignored, merged, or whatnot

Comment: @Augie Gardner: I had the same question but seemingly mongodump discards all indices. Docs at https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongodump/ say:
`mongodump output only captures the documents in the database and does not include index data.`